# Android Studio 3 - can't find files from project

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Since recently it occures more and more often to me that I just can't open files with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> - it shows only those from SDK, not the ones from the project. I imported options from AS 2.3.3 and using 3.0.1 right now (though it occured for 3.0.0 as well). How can I fix that? Am I in some sort of scope I'm not aware of? The problem vanishes after invalidate + restart, but it's very inconvenient.